# Barman: rsync wal archival stalls on some files

Tags: postgresql, rsync, zfs, sparse-files

I'm archiving wal files from a postgres server via rsync, most of the time the archiving works fine and is quick, the speedtest for the connection is here: (this goes via the internet)

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  9.30 MBytes  78.0 Mbits/sec    0    395 KBytes
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  66.3 MBytes   556 Mbits/sec   14   1.05 MBytes
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  75.0 MBytes   629 Mbits/sec    0   1.16 MBytes
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  81.2 MBytes   682 Mbits/sec    0   1.24 MBytes
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  86.2 MBytes   724 Mbits/sec    0   1.30 MBytes
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  88.8 MBytes   744 Mbits/sec    0   1.34 MBytes
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  91.2 MBytes   765 Mbits/sec    0   1.37 MBytes
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  92.5 MBytes   776 Mbits/sec    0   1.38 MBytes
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  93.8 MBytes   786 Mbits/sec    0   1.39 MBytes
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  63.8 MBytes   535 Mbits/sec   22    535 KBytes
```

So, more than enough bandwidth available.

But on some WAL files it just **crawls to a slow and it takes 30 - 50 seconds** until the 16 MB file is transferred, and I'm at a loss where to debug / look for the issue.

The rsync command looks like this:

```
rsync -p --chmod=Fg+r,Fo+r --timeout 10 -e /usr/bin/ssh -i /var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/id_rsa -a pg_wal/000000080000A5500000005D barman@barman_host/data/database/pg/incoming/000000080000A5500000005D
```

I looked at rsync via strace on the receiving side, and it seems that just the packets from the sending side were not arriving fast enough.
I tried to cat the file via ssh and output it on my console, that was finished before the rsync transfer.
I tried to cat it to /dev/null, that was instant.

So I assume the source drive is fast enough.

I transferred a bulk of WAL files (60GB) via a single rsync command, that was also quick and averaged 65 MB/s, so that would tell me that everything works fine, still some files are slow.

What else can I look at?
How can I figure out if the issue is sending side, internet speed, receiving side, are there some special logs I can activate on rsync?
Can I check the timings of the syscalls via strace?

```
ls -l 000000080000A578000000E8
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Jul 19 07:32 000000080000A578000000E8
bash-4.2$ du -sh 000000080000A578000000E8
11M 000000080000A578000000E8
bash-4.2$ du -sh 000000080000A578000000E8 --apparent-size
16M 000000080000A578000000E8
```

WAL drive is a ZFS with compression active, therefore the difference.

Also for completion, all zfs properties:

```
storage/database  type                  filesystem                       -
storage/database  creation              Thu Apr 19 12:22 2018            -
storage/database  used                  1.33T                            -
storage/database  available             369G                             -
storage/database  referenced            1.33T                            -
storage/database  compressratio         2.13x                            -
storage/database  mounted               yes                              -
storage/database  quota                 none                             default
storage/database  reservation           none                             default
storage/database  recordsize            16K                              inherited from storage
storage/database  mountpoint            /data/                        
local
storage/database  sharenfs              off                              default
storage/database  checksum              on                               default
storage/database  compression           lz4                              inherited from storage
storage/database  atime                 off                              inherited from storage
storage/database  devices               on                               default
storage/database  exec                  on                               default
storage/database  setuid                on                               default
storage/database  readonly              off                              default
storage/database  zoned                 off                              default
storage/database  snapdir               hidden                           default
storage/database  aclinherit            restricted                       default
storage/database  createtxg             1159021                          -
storage/database  canmount              on                               default
storage/database  xattr                 sa                               inherited from storage
storage/database  copies                1                                default
storage/database  version               5                                -
storage/database  utf8only              off                              -
storage/database  normalization         none                             -
storage/database  casesensitivity       sensitive                        -
storage/database  vscan                 off                              default
storage/database  nbmand                off                              default
storage/database  sharesmb              off                              default
storage/database  refquota              none                             default
storage/database  refreservation        none                             default
storage/database  guid                  8214081110063784152              -
storage/database  primarycache          all                              default
storage/database  secondarycache        all                              default
storage/database  usedbysnapshots       0B                               -
storage/database  usedbydataset         1.33T                            -
storage/database  usedbychildren        0B                               -
storage/database  usedbyrefreservation  0B                               -
storage/database  logbias               throughput                       inherited from storage
storage/database  dedup                 off                              default
storage/database  mlslabel              none                             default
storage/database  sync                  disabled                         local
storage/database  dnodesize             legacy                           default
storage/database  refcompressratio      2.13x                            -
storage/database  written               1.33T                            -
storage/database  logicalused           2.82T                            -
storage/database  logicalreferenced     2.82T                            -
storage/database  volmode               default                          default
storage/database  filesystem_limit      none                             default
storage/database  snapshot_limit        none                             default
storage/database  filesystem_count      none                             default
storage/database  snapshot_count        none                             default
storage/database  snapdev               hidden                           default
storage/database  acltype               off                              default
storage/database  context               none                             default
storage/database  fscontext             none                             default
storage/database  defcontext            none                             default
storage/database  rootcontext           none                             default
storage/database  relatime              off                              default
storage/database  redundant_metadata    all                              default
storage/database  overlay               off                              default
```

But nothing was changed in the past days on the ZFS drive - and this whole issue just started on Friday (17th July).

Also, if I copy paste the command, and run it again, it finishes instantly - the still running command will continue to hang.

With ls -lah you can follow how the temporary file gets bigger and bigger (around 150 KB/s)

Thanks for anyone taking time to read this!

Edit: I added timing recording to the wal archive process, here's the result:

```
000000080000A57C00000034 1
000000080000A57C00000035 0
000000080000A57C00000036 0
000000080000A57C00000037 1
000000080000A57C00000038 1
000000080000A57C00000039 119
000000080000A57C0000003A 2
000000080000A57C0000003B 1
000000080000A57C0000003C 127
000000080000A57C0000003D 2
000000080000A57C0000003E 1
000000080000A57C0000003F 1
000000080000A57C00000040 1
000000080000A57C00000041 1
000000080000A57C00000042 1
000000080000A57C00000043 1
000000080000A57C00000044 1
000000080000A57C00000045 1
000000080000A57C00000046 1
000000080000A57C00000047 1
000000080000A57C00000048 1
000000080000A57C00000049 105
000000080000A57C0000004A 2
000000080000A57C0000004B 2
000000080000A57C0000004C 1
000000080000A57C0000004D 1
000000080000A57C0000004E 118
000000080000A57C0000004F 2
000000080000A57C00000050 1
000000080000A57C00000051 120
000000080000A57C00000052 2
000000080000A57C00000053 1
```

The number on the right is seconds it took to execute the Rsync command for the specified file.

Edit 2:

I have recreated the issue with 2 ram drives on each side. I extracted the ports used and have found they are all even (might be a hint)

I have switched between internet connections on my side (target) and the problem went away. Based on discussions it seems to be a network issue over a certain path (maybe due to Load Balancing)

I will update with the final resolution.

Edit 3:

Our provider is Hetzner, they had a fault in one of their DECIX modules (https://www.hetzner-status.de/#16045). After the deactivation the issue went away.

Comment: 16MB != 11MB. Your file is a sparse file. Add option `--sparse` to your rsync.

Comment: it is not a sparse file, it's a compressed file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the fault was network related as initially thought, I would recommend anyone to follow the same steps.

1. Repeat the same transfer outside of your application, collect metrics for runtime, ports in use, routing paths
2. Repeat to multiple different internet connections that are routed differently
3. Contact your internet provider / hosting provider with the information

Keeping this question open makes no sense, since it's an intermittent issue, but maybe someone in the future might have the same.